# Creating Arraylist of Arraylist by slicing existing arraylist

Tags: powershell, arraylist, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have the following variable defined

```
$A =  New-Object -TypeName "System.Collections.ArrayList"
```

Now I add `n` elements to it :

```
$A.Add(1..n)
```

Now I want to divide `$A` into `p` parts of `k` elements each(The last one might have lesser elements if `p*k>$A.count`).
How do I do that?

Comment: I think this will need more background information of what more specifically try to achieve. As a starter: why are you using a dotnet `[Arraylist]` class instead of the native PowerShell pipeline? See: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a function to split an array into several smaller arrays. 
Below a slighty adapted version of that function found [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Split-an-array-into-parts-4357dcc1):

```
function Split-Array {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParametersetName = 'ByChunkSize')]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        $Array,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1, ParameterSetName = 'ByChunkSize')]
        [ValidateRange(1,[int]::MaxValue)]
        [int]$ChunkSize,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 1, ParameterSetName = 'ByParts')]
        [ValidateRange(1,[int]::MaxValue)]
        [int]$Parts
    )

    $items = $Array.Count
    switch ($PsCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
        'ByChunkSize'  { $Parts = [Math]::Ceiling($items / $ChunkSize) }
        'ByParts'      { $ChunkSize = [Math]::Ceiling($items / $Parts) }
        default        { throw "Split-Array: You must use either the Parts or the ChunkSize parameter" }
    }

    # when the given ChunkSize is larger or equal to the number of items in the array
    # use TWO unary commas to return the array as single sub array of the result.
    if ($ChunkSize -ge $items) { return ,,$Array }

    $result = for ($i = 1; $i -le $Parts; $i++) {
        $first = (($i - 1) * $ChunkSize)
        $last  = [Math]::Min(($i * $ChunkSize) - 1, $items - 1)
        ,$Array[$first..$last]
    }

    return ,$result
}
```

In your case you could use it like:

```
$p = 4  # the number of parts you want
$subArrays = Split-Array $A.ToArray() -Parts $p
```

or

```
$k = 4  # the max number items in each part
$subArrays = Split-Array $A.ToArray() -ChunkSize $k
```

Comment: When size of  `$A` is lesser than `chunksize` it should return only 1 chunk right? but it returns the number of chunks which equals to the size of `$A`.

Comment: @sporty_1993 Hm... you're right. I haven't tested a case like that I admit. I have edited the answer to deal with such events.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I came up with to chunk your [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netcore-3.1) into a nested array list of `p` parts. It uses a [`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?view=netcore-3.1) to group the size `k` chunks by `index / chunksize`, which is then rounded down to the nearest integer using [`System.Math.Floor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.floor?view=netcore-3.1). It then only fetches the groups with keys from `0` to `$Parts`.

```
function Split-ArrayList {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        # Arraylist to slice
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [System.Collections.ArrayList]
        $ArrayList,
        # Chunk size per part
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateRange(1, [int]::MaxValue)]
        [int]
        $ChunkSize,
        # Number of parts
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateRange(1, [int]::MaxValue)]
        [int]
        $Parts
    )

    # Group chunks into hashtable
    $chunkGroups = [ordered]@{}
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $ArrayList.Count; $i++) {

        # Get the hashtable key by dividing the index by the chunk size
        # Round down to nearest integer using Math.Floor
        [int]$key = [Math]::Floor($i / $ChunkSize)

        # Add new arraylist for key if it doesn't exist
        # ContainsKey is not supported for ordered dictionary
        if ($chunkGroups.Keys -notcontains $key) {
            $chunkGroups.Add($key, [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new())
        }

        # Add number to hashtable
        [void]$chunkGroups[$key].Add($ArrayList[$i])
    }

    # Create nested ArrayList of parts
    $result = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
    for ($key = 0; $key -lt $Parts; $key++) {
        [void]$result.Add($chunkGroups[$key])
    }

    $result
}
```

**Usage:**

```
$A = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new(1..10)

Split-ArrayList -ArrayList $A -ChunkSize 4 -Parts 1 | 
    ForEach-Object { "{ " + ($_ -join ", ") + " }" }

# { 1, 2, 3, 4 }

Split-ArrayList -ArrayList $A -ChunkSize 4 -Parts 2 | 
    ForEach-Object { "{ " + ($_ -join ", ") + " }" }

# { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
# { 5, 6, 7, 8 }

Split-ArrayList -ArrayList $A -ChunkSize 4 -Parts 3 | 
    ForEach-Object { "{ " + ($_ -join ", ") + " }" }

# { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
# { 5, 6, 7, 8 }
# { 9, 10 }
```

**Note:** I didn't really account for the cases where you might want to exclude `Parts`, so I made every parameter mandatory. You can amend the function to be more flexible with different inputs.